# How to display a function using streamlit

Tags: python, streamlit

I'm new to streamlit and trying to display a function using st.write, however, something is not working properly. This is the code that I have:

```
def ecc_display(ecc_duration_percentage): 
  if ecc_duration_percentage < 5:
    return str(ecc_duration_percentage) + "good"
  else:
    return str(ecc_duration_percentage) + " not good."

st.write(ecc_display)
```

The code itself doesn't display any issues but I don't get the output I'm looking for. This is what I'm getting right now:

> **main**.ecc_display(ecc_duration_percentage)
> No docs available.

Comment: Surely you want to display *the result of calling the function*, rather than the function itself?  That would be written `st.write(ecc_display(X))`, where `X` is whatever value you want to use for the percentage parameter to the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def ecc_display(ecc_duration_percentage): 
  if ecc_duration_percentage < 5:
    return str(ecc_duration_percentage) + " good"
  else:
    return str(ecc_duration_percentage) + " not good."

# start
ecc_duration_percentage = 1.0
value = ecc_display(ecc_duration_percentage)
st.write(value)
```